# Notification limit dropped to 24 per app in Android 11 notification drawer

Tags: android, xamarin.android

Is there any limit on the number of notifications the android app can display? I am facing an issue after 24 notifications android notification does not appear.

There is no documentation which states this clearly.

This issue I have observed in Android 11. Looks like this is applicable to android 10 (https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/23619509?hl=en). I don't have android 10. So, I have not tested.

Please help me to get a documentation reference for this limit or this behavior can be changed using the settings of the device.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is a limit of notifications that can be posted per app. The interesting thing was the number is not fixed and can be controlled by the Device Manufacturer. From my observation, a Google Pixel 3A phone had limited to 25 notifications were as an OnePlus 6T and a Samsung device had limited the notifications to 50.

If we carefully observe the [NotificationManagerService.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e57464d905037dfb269a221963d91f65b288288/services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java#106) source code, we can see a variable `MAX_PACKAGE_COUNT` declared to be 50.

And inside the [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/0e57464d905037dfb269a221963d91f65b288288/services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java#1423), it checks if the count is greater than the `MAX_PACKAGE_NOTIFICATIONS`, it has a message saying that “Package has. already posted max toasts. Not showing more!”
This is the reason we get limited by the number of notifications that are posted per app.

Comment: Leo Zhu - MSFT, Could you please help me understand how this referenced code is related to Android 11 or Android 10?

Comment: but why social apps like whatsapp can post more than 50 notification in system tray in android 11 ?

Answer (score 0):

- The number of notifications for a particular application has been set to 50 which is a default value set in [notification manager](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/core/java/com/android/server/notification/NotificationManagerService.java). But more on that, the device manufacturer can also set this limit on their own.
- Problem  : Now the problem is that we can not change this number as it is not accessible to us or even visible.
- Solution : If we want that our application delivers notifications continuously, we need to change a little bit of code in our application.

  - We have to clear the previous notifications which are not needed.
  - For that we can set Notification.builder.

  NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(...);
  builder.setContentTitle(...);
  builder.setContentText(...);
  builder.setTimeoutAfter(5000);

> builder.setTimeoutAfter(5000);
> The above line will auto-clear notifications after 5 seconds of notification arrival.

So newer notifications can be pushed by your application.

References : 1. [Notification builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder)
2. [builder.setTimeOutAfter();](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setTimeoutAfter(long))