# Local notification occurs but doesn't appear on the screen

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, sockets, notifications

Although the notifications sent by the application are high priority and grouped, when frequent notifications are sent, the notifications begin to not shown after a while. When I examine the logs in my code, I can see that the local notification has occurred. Why are the notifications not showing after sending frequent notifications?

```kotlin
    fun getChatChannels(): MutableList<NotificationChannel> {

    val chatChannels = mutableListOf<NotificationChannel>()

    val chatChannel = NotificationChannel(
        IM_CHANNEL_ID,
        Application.getString(R.string.chat_channel_name),
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
    )

    chatChannel.setShowBadge(false)
    chatChannel.group = MESSAGE_GROUP_ID

    chatChannels.add(chatChannel)

    return chatChannels }



    private fun getChannelList(): MutableList<NotificationChannel> {

    val channelList = mutableListOf<NotificationChannel>()
    channelList.addAll(getChatChannels())

    return channelList
    }


    fun createGroupsAndChannels() {

    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

        val notificationManager =
            Application.instance.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        notificationManager.createNotificationChannelGroups(getGroupList())
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannels(getChannelList())
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Channels and groups created")
     }



    fun showChatNotification(destinationAddress: String, messageId: String, message: String) {
     ThreadManager.createUITask {
            val name = if (domainContact != null) {
                "${domainContact.firstName} ${domainContact.lastName}"
            } else {
                destinationAddress
            }

            val notificationIntent = Intent(Application.instance, MainActivity::class.java)
            notificationIntent.putExtra(
                Application.getString(R.string.key_conversation_participant),
                destinationAddress
            )
            notificationIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS

            val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                Application.instance,
                destinationAddress.hashCode(),
                notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            )
            val notificationId = UUID.randomUUID().hashCode()

            val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(Application.instance, IM_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_message)
                .setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(Application.instance, R.color.colorPrimary))
                .setContentTitle(name)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setStyle(
                    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle() // Expandable-Collapsible notification
                        .bigText(message)
                )
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setCategory(NotificationCompat.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setVisibility(VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                .setAutoCancel(true)

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                builder.addAction(getChatNotificationReplyAction(destinationAddress, notificationId, messageId))
            }

            chatNotifications.add(mapOf(destinationAddress to notificationId))
            createNotifications(builder, notificationId)

            Log.d(TAG, "Chat notification created")
        } 


  private fun createNotifications(builder: NotificationCompat.Builder, notificationId: Int) {

        with(NotificationManagerCompat.from(Application.instance)) {
            notify(notificationId, builder.build())
        }
    }
```

Comment: please add enough code for us to recreate the issue

Comment: ı added @a_local_nobody

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did u create NotificationChannel if the android os is equal to or bigger than Oreo?
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
I create a notification in the service and start the notification service when I want to update the notification message.
I tested update every second for message value and the value will change over 50 times.
MyNotificationService.java

```
package com.urpackage.test;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.text.TextUtils;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MyNotificationService extends Service {
    Context mContext;
    Notification notification = null;
    private final int notificationId=12321;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mContext=this.getApplicationContext();

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);;
        notificationManager.cancel(notificationId);
        builder =null;
        super.onDestroy();

    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder =null ;
    private void createNotification(String message) {
        try {
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)mContext.getSystemService(mContext.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            if(builder==null)
            {
                String packageName=mContext.getClass().getPackage().getName();
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                intent.setClass(this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
                //activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE);
                //Notification notification = null;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {

                    NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                            packageName,
                            "MyChannel",
                            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
                    //channelLove.setDescription("最重要的人");
                    //channelLove.enableLights(true);
                    //channelLove.enableVibration(true);

                    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

                    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplication(), packageName)
                            .setAutoCancel(false).setOngoing(true)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24).setTicker("MyChannelN")
                            .setContentTitle("MyChannelN")
                            //.setContentText(message).
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                } else {
                    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplication(), packageName)
                            .setAutoCancel(false).setOngoing(true)
                            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_baseline_play_circle_filled_24).setTicker("MyChannelN")
                            .setContentTitle("MyChannelN")
                            //.setContentText(message).
                            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
                }
            }
            // notificationId is a unique int for each notification that you must define
            builder.setContentText(message);
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Bundle bundle=null;
        if(intent!=null)
            bundle=intent.getExtras();
        String message="Running";
        if(bundle!=null)
            message=bundle.getString("NotificationMessage","Running");
        createNotification(message);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }
}
```

To use the service

> Intent MyNotificationServiceIntent = new Intent(this, >MyNotificationService.class);
> MyNotificationServiceIntent.putExtra("NotificationMessage", "your message");
> startService(MyNotificationServiceIntent);

Comment: I used it.My problem is that notifications stop showing when they are sent too many times in a row. In the logs, I see the output of notification created.

Comment: try to use a fixed notification id value instead of random then test again. Like this [final int notificationId=12321;]

Comment: I tried but it didn't work. Afterwards, I noticed that when a certain notification accumulates at the top, the notifications begin to not show. When I delete the notifications above, the notification keeps coming back. Is there such a limitation? what can i do about it?

Comment: after research, pls ref to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65341875/notification-limit-dropped-to-24-per-app-in-android-11-notification-drawer

Comment: I noticed this limitation and I made my corrections, but now, instead of destroying the notification by swiping to the side, when I swipe up, the notification doesn't. Any ideas on how I can change this feature?